# Could someone give me a good progression of projects to grow my skills in python from novice to intermediate at least?

Tags: python

I recently began to teach myself how to program in python. At the moment I am struggling to structure my learning through projects like I had in my programming classes. I was wondering if anyone had a short list of projects that they feel best develop the skills they find most useful in python or somewhere I could find good projects to challenge myself to grow.

Thanks

Comment: These kind of questions are [out of scope](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for stack overflow, but I recently saw [this](https://web.eecs.utk.edu/~azh/blog/challengingprojects.html) article and they may be worth a look. Some will need a lower level language but some will be perfectly doable in python.

Answer (score 1):

The self-learning tool I found most useful was "[Automate the Boring Stuff with Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/)". The chapters and hands-on projects stuck much better than DataCamp, CodeAcademy, Udemy, etc. Just set up an IDE or Jupyter Notebook and create along with the chapters. Then, once you've made some things, improv a little on them to make them your own.

Good luck and enjoy.

Comment: This is a very good resource indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Download your bank statement and write a parser to generate a spending report.

Answer (score 0):

Google (or alternatives like Lilo) is your friend.

Here is some of the results I got by typing "Python Exercises":

- https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/
- https://www.practicepython.org/exercise/2014/04/30/13-fibonacci.html

Some trainers also offer some paying "Weekly Practice": every week you got some challenge (usually different level to choose at the beginning), and at the end of the week you get the solution.

Can't give any name though because StackOverflow is not about promoting